# В git status одни и те же файлы в разных секциях

Tags: git

Здесь что-то пошло не так или я что-то не понимаю?

```
C:\Users\paul\Workspace\someproject>git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 57 commits.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       new file:   common/models/SmsQueue.php
#       new file:   console/components/Sms/Factory.php
#       new file:   console/components/Sms/Gateway.php
#       new file:   console/controllers/SmsQueueController.php
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   common/models/SmsQueue.php
#       modified:   console/components/Sms/Factory.php
#       modified:   console/components/Sms/Gateway.php
#       modified:   console/config/params.php
#       modified:   console/controllers/SmsQueueController.php
#
```

Версия Git:

```
C:\Users\paul\Workspace\someproject>git --version
git version 1.8.3.msysgit.0
```

Как одни и те же файлы могут быть одновременно и "Changes to be committed", и "Changes not staged for commit"?

Comment: да, вы явно не знаете, что такое `index`, оно же `stage area`, оно же `staged files` в *git-е*. по этим поисковым запросам можно найти множество информации. например, 1. [Why the index/staging area is so useful](http://gitolite.com/uses-of-index.html), 2. [the staging area](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/18/the-staging-area.html) и т.д. и т.п.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Значит файлы были исправлены после того, как они были добавлены в `stage`. Никакого бага здесь нет. После любого изменения нужно помещать файл в `stage`, иначе это изменение не попадёт в ближайший commit.

Answer (score 2):

А можно ещё добавить файл в коммит не полностью, а частично с помощью `git add --patch filename.x`. git будет спрашивать для каждого куска изменений - добавлять его или нет. Это позволит добавить только часть изменений с файла на коммит. В этом случае также можно добиться приведенного выше поведения git'а.